# Handling templates without a module name specified

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I have a 3rd party extension installed and I needed to overwrite on block because I could not use events or plugins on it.
The block is added in the layout file like this:

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block" name="some-name" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
```

Notice that there is no module name specified for the template.

I've overwritten it with this in my `di.xml`

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Block" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Block" />
```

now when loading a certain page I get the error `path/to/template.phtml` does not exist.

I know I can solve this by redeclaring the block in my own layout file and making the template `Vendor_Module::path/to/module.phtml` and it will work but this is not upgrade proof.
If I upgrade the extension and the template to that specific block changes I will have problems.

My question: Is there an upgrade proof way to overwrite blocks and still keep the templates from the original module?

Comment: I guess that the only solution in that case Plugin. Using plugin over this block on `getTemplate()` you can keep the original module template if you will upgrade the module

Comment: I don't think I need a plugin since I've already overwritten it

Comment: Since you have your own block you may copy the constructor from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and  add the "Vendor_Module::" to the configured template path if no vendor/module prefix is set.

Comment: @Marius ,Why you donot change template using gettemplate function at your rewrite class .

Comment: @AmitBera. Change it to what?

Comment: mean override getTemplate method from rewrite class

Comment: `<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block;


class MyClass  extends \Vendor\Module\Block\OriginalClass
{
    public function getTemplate() {
        $OriginaLmoduleTenmplate = parent::getTemplate();
        return 'Vendor_Module::path/to/module.phtml';
        
    }
}
`

Comment: This would be the constructor approach - in that way you could set other templates too: `protected function _construct()
  {
   parent::_construct();
   if ($this->hasData('template')) {
    if (strpos( $this->getData('template') , "::") === false){
     $this->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::".$this->getData('template'));
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas, Based on them, I came up with a method that should work and be upgrade proof, in case the vendor changes the template that is used.

Comment: Pretty cool.Just like a tricky solution.But Best solution is plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I was able solve my problem by adding this method to my block

```
public function getTemplate()
{
    $template = parent::getTemplate();
    $parts = \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository::extractModule($template);
    if (empty($parts[0])) {
        $template = 'Vendor_Module'.\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository::FILE_ID_SEPARATOR.$template;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

This way, if the template has a a module specified it will use that template, if not tell magento to load it from the original vendor module.